# Cannot attach Event listener to canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I've got some very simple code that attempts to attach an event listener and call a function on mousemove, so that I can find the mouse position within a canvas element:

```
canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_canvas_move, false);

function on_canvas_move(ev) {
    var x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    $('#status').html(x +', '+ y);
}
```

However I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'addEventListener'

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: This just needs a comment- use document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a `nodeList` (like an array of DOM objects) so you need to designate which element in that `nodeList` you want to add the listener to.

And secondly, your event handler `on_canvas_move()` also has the same issue as `canvas.offsetLeft` would be trying to read the `.offsetLeft` property on the nodeList, not on the DOM element.  That would give you an `undefined` value and trying to do math with `undefined` gives you `NaN`.

To add just one:

```
canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
canvas[0].addEventListener('mousemove', on_canvas_move, false);

function on_canvas_move(ev) {
    var x = ev.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    $('#status').html(x +', '+ y);
}
```

Or, to add all of them:

```
canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
   canvas[i].addEventListener('mousemove', on_canvas_move, false);
}

function on_canvas_move(ev) {
    var x = ev.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    $('#status').html(x +', '+ y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If you could perhaps quickly clarify why I'm getting NaN on x,y values?

Comment: @Megh - for the same reason.  `canvas.offsetLeft` is trying to get `offsetLeft` on an array, not on a DOM element in that array.  I updated my answer to show a new version of `on_canvas_move()`.

Comment: Technically it returns a NodeList, not an array.

Comment: @Dennis - technically correct and I've edited my answer to use that term, though it doesn't change the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns you an array - you should either loop it and bind the listener, or point to the element you need:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].addEventListener( ... )
```

An advice - when you don't know what's going on, figure it yourself by printing out stuff to console - `console.log(canvas)` would have told you.

Comment: The `.getElements` with a plural should have also told.